# Python3:Save File to Specified Location

Tags: python

I have a rather simple program that writes HTML code ready for use.

It works fine, except that if one were to run the program from the Python command line, as is the default, the HTML file that is created is created where **python.exe** is, not where the program I wrote is. And that's a problem.

Do you know a way of getting the `.write()` function to write a file to a specific location on the disc `(e.g. C:\Users\User\Desktop)?`

Extra cool-points if you know how to open a file browser window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is probably that you are not including the full path when you open the file for writing.  For details on opening a web browser, read [this fine manual](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/webbrowser.html).

```
import os
target_dir = r"C:\full\path\to\where\you\want\it"

fullname = os.path.join(target_dir,filename)
with open(fullname,"w") as f:
   f.write("<html>....</html>")

import webbrowser

url = "file://"+fullname.replace("\\","/")
webbrowser.open(url,True,True)
```

BTW: the code is the same in python 2.6.

Answer (score 0):

I'll admit I don't know Python 3, so I may be wrong, but in Python 2, you can just check the `__file__` variable in your module to get the name of the file it was loaded from. Just create your file in that same directory (preferably using os.path.dirname and os.path.join to remain platform-independent).